# Like Button doesn't work when I return on the link?

Tags: facebook

Ok, this is the iframe I get from official API

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gabbatracklistworld.com%2Findex.php%3Fexplore%3Dview%26trackid%3D586&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21&amp;appId=225322387567317" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

it works well! I click Like, and I see on facebook that I LIKE that page. BUT, when I click from Facebook to the link, going to that page :

```
http://www.gabbatracklistworld.com/index.php?explore=view&trackid=586&fb_action_ids=10200316597536577&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210200316597536577%22%3A10151528903177923%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210200316597536577%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D
```

I see that "I don't like it" anymore. Seems that querystring added by Facebook is another location than previous page.

Is it a bug? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

and paste http://www.gabbatracklistworld.com/index.php?explore=view&trackid=586
and then press get code. You'll see a tab called iframe. It says:

> This plugin does not have an iframe implementation with the selected
>   options. Please use the JavaScript SDK and the HTML5 or XFBML
>   implementations, or change the value of the send parameter.

You need to use the first implementation, embed the javascript sdk, and create the like button using html5 or xfbml. The tabs explain exactly how.